# ETL - query needed

Tags: sql, etl

Having 3 tables same columns but with different values..result should be only same combination would be printed in the result set

example
table a

```
col x  col y
23     a01
23     a02
24     a11
25     a12
```

table b

```
col x  col y
23     a10
23     a02
24     a11
25     a12
```

table c

```
col x  col y
23     a01
23     a02
24     a11
25     a12
```

want the result as

```
col x  col y
24     a11
25     a12
```

please help us to get the query

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried/)

Answer (score 1):

Not familiar with ETL, but if it's just plain SQL it should be something like this:

```
select a.*
from a
inner join b on a.x = b.x and a.y=b.y
inner join c on a.x = c.x and a.y=c.y
```

Comment: ETL means "Extract, Transform, Load" and generally refers to converting data from one format to another. It's not a specific technology.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the INTERSECT operator if you want to identify identical rows in different tables

```
WITH CTE_T1 AS
(
   SELECT [X] ,[Y]
   FROM
      (VALUES  
          (23, 'a01')
         ,(23, 'a02')
         ,(24, 'a11')
         ,(25, 'a12')
     ) T1([X],[Y])
),
CTE_T2 AS
(
   SELECT [X] ,[Y]
   FROM
      (VALUES  
          (23, 'a10')
         ,(23, 'a20')
         ,(24, 'a11')
         ,(25, 'a12')
     ) T2([X],[Y])
),
CTE_T3 AS
(
   SELECT [X] ,[Y]
   FROM
      (VALUES  
          (23, 'a40')
         ,(23, 'a50')
         ,(24, 'a11')
         ,(25, 'a12')
     ) T3([X],[Y])
)
SELECT [X],[Y] FROM CTE_T1
INTERSECT 
SELECT [X],[Y] FROM CTE_T2
INTERSECT 
SELECT [X],[Y] FROM CTE_T3
```

This statement produces the following result

```
X           Y
----------- ----
24          a11
25          a12

(2 row(s) affected)
```